# Problems when using Db2 Developer-C Edition from Docker on Mac

Tags: docker, db2

(I am rewriting this question from [another site](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/426985/using-db2-developer-c-edition-from-docker-on-mac.html) to get more attention, I hope it is ok.)

I am trying to setup a Db2 developer environment following instruction from https://store.docker.com/images/db2-developer-c-edition.

I am able to create the container, start it and do even some sql queries

```
mkdir docker_volume
# I use the same env_list as the instructions link above
docker run -h db2server_myDb \
    --name db2server \
    --restart=always  \
    --detach \
    --privileged=true  \
    -p 50000 \
    --env-file .env_list \
    -v docker_volume:/database \
    store/ibmcorp/db2_developer_c:11.1.2.2
docker exec -ti db2server bash -c "su db2inst1"
db2 connect to testdb
db2 "create table t_project ( code varchar(5), name varchar(60) )"
db2 "insert into t_project (code, name) values (57003, 'sample')"
db2 "select * from t_project"
```

So far everything seems ok.

### Problems:

1. I am **NOT** able to connect to db from the host. How can I connect to this db from my macos machine? I am trying host: `172.17.0.1` port: `50000` Database: `testdb` username: `db2inst1` password: `password`
2. After stopping the container I am **NOT** able to start it again. What is the correct command to start or stop my db2 container?

   ```
   $ docker stop db2server
   $ docker start -ia db2server
   (output)
   ...
   DB2 State : Operable
   DB2 has not been started
   Starting DB2...
   01/26/2018 03:21:38     0   0   SQL1063N  DB2START processing was successful.
   SQL1063N  DB2START processing was successful.
   mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/log/supervisor': File exists
   Unlinking stale socket /var/run/supervisor.sock
   (*) All databases are now active. 
   (*) Setup has completed.
   false

   2018-01-26-03.21.38.860516+000 I342573E395           LEVEL: Warning
   PID     : 629                  TID : 140077563770752 PROC : db2start
   INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
   HOSTNAME: db2server_myDb
   FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleReleaseStStLockFile, probe:15795
   MESSAGE : Released lock on the file:
   DATA #1 : String, 50 bytes
   /database/config/db2inst1/sqllib/ctrl/db2strst.lck
   ```

I am stuck here and I need to terminate the process and remove the container and re-do everything again.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Docker Store image of DB2 Developer-C.  If you following the instructions for creating the container, you will notice that the instructions specify to use the option `-p 50000` for `docker run`. This option specifies that port 50000 in the container will be bound to a *dynamic* port on the host machine.

You need to check to see what port is attached on the host computer.  You can see this in the output from `docker ps` or, better, from `docker port`:

```
$ docker port db2serverX
50000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32777
```

This shows that port 50000 in the container is mapped to port 32777 on (all) interfaces on the Docker host.

If you would like to specify the port you connect to on your Docker host, make sure to use the format `-p 50000:50000`, where you are specifying `hostPort:containerPort`.